# How to get attributes from a Backbone model fetching Django auth backend API

Tags: javascript, django, backbone.js

I'm using django auth backend, Django REST framework API and Backbone in a project.

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: host + 'api/users/'
});

// django auth response
var isAuthenticated = {{ request.user.is_authenticated|yesno:"true,false" }};
if (isAuthenticated){
  var userID = {{ request.user.id }}; // django user id
  console.log(userID); // checking value
  var currentUser = new User({id: userID});
  currentUser.fetch();
  var username = currentUser.get('username');
  console.log(currentUser); // checking value
```

Result for `console.log(currentUser)`

```
attributes: Object
    email: "y****@*****m"
    first_name: ""
    id: 1
    is_staff: true
    last_name: ""
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/1/"
    username: "yorsant"
```

How to read the `attributes:Object`?

Comment: Hey Yordan, I'm assuming you're using Django Rest Framework? Can you post how you're API is working? The views.py may help, as well as what the current response is returning.

Comment: `{
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/1/",
    "username": "yorsant",
    "email": "y*****@****m",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "is_staff": true
}`  api results. I edit the question, the model is fetching, I don't know how to get the values.

Comment: I'm using ModelViewSet and HyperlinkedModelSerializer

Comment: Do you have any experience with ajax? `fetch` is async, it needs to make a roundtrip to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [Eric said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42882442/how-to-get-attributes-from-a-backbone-model-fetching-django-auth-backend-api/42894837#comment72883752_42882442), `fetch` is async.

You see the data in the console because the time you took to explore the object was enough for the round-trip to the API to complete.

[image: Object initial appearance in the console]
[image: Object after being evaluated by the console]

The Chrome dev tools console keeps a reference to the object being logged, then when the user interacts with it (collapse the object with a click), a little `!` beside the object is shown and you can read:

> Value below was evaluated just now.

Backbone [Model `fetch` function](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) offers different options you can pass, like a `success` callback.

```
currentUser.fetch({
    success: function() {
        console.log("username:", currentUser.get('username'));
    }
});
```

Knowing this, in a Backbone view, you could use [Backbone's events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) to know when the attributes are ready to use.

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);
        this.model.fetch();
    },

    // this is called when the model's sync event is fired, so
    // when the model's attributes are ready.
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

> **"sync"** `(model_or_collection, response, options)` — when a model or
>   collection has been successfully synced with the server.

Comment: Thanks @EmileBergeron, I understand better now.